# What to use instead of Class.newInstance()?

Tags: java, reflection

`Class.newInstance()` is marked deprecated. Documentation does not suggest any alternatives. How are we meant to create instances now?

Comment: [Which documentation?](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--)

Answer (score 261, accepted):

To quote [Java 9's javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--):

> The call
>
> `clazz.newInstance()`
>
> can be replaced by
>
> `clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`

Comment: What about java 8?. I can't find getDeclaredConstructor() method  without parameters 
 there.

Comment: @YuriiKozachok You could use `getConstrouctor`, although note it will only return **public** constructors. Also, note that `newInstance` isn't deprecated in Java 8 (although using it still has all the problems that made the JDK developers deprecate it in 9...)

Comment: @Shtefan Where are you seeing that? The java 17 docs don't mark it as deprecated AFAICT: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)

Comment: @elhefe `newInstance` isn't deprecated. Using `newInstance` on a class IS deprecated.

Comment: It looks like the comment I replied to is deleted, but from what I recall (and maybe I'm wrong) it was saying `Constructor.newInstance()` was deprecated.

Comment: @YuriiKozachok `getDeclaredConstructor(Class<?>... paramTypes)` is variadic - so you can invoke it with 0 arguments.

Answer (score 26):

```
Class.getDeclaredConstructor(...).newInstance(...)
```

Refer to [Google errorprone's documentation](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/ClassNewInstance) (for example) for a description of why.