# facing problem for Using Reflection in java

Tags: java

**This is my main class :-**

```
import io.*;
import processors.*;
import utilities.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        AbstractCalcIO cio = null;
            //read properties file to know which type of operation needed.
            //then create appropriate class based on that.
        try {
            String opm = PropertyReader.getProperty("config.properties","opmode");

            System.out.println("Got input class name: "+opm);
                //get the class object from the name of the input class
            Class c = Class.forName(opm);
                //then cast it to AbstractCalcIO and then assign it to cio object
            Object obj = c.newInstance();

            cio = (AbstractCalcIO)obj;

            if(cio != null)
            {
                cio.startOperations();
            }   
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

In this project, i use the Abstraction class, 3-IO class for input control, exception class and so on. Here I use the reflection for avoiding the code duplication. Here is also a properties file that controls the functionality. But in the main class where i use the reflection then i'm getting an notification. For this reason my project file is not compiled. I think it happens for java version, i use javac 10.0.2. So, what will be the solution?

In the main class, the reflection code section is :-

```
                Class c = Class.forName(opm);
                    //then cast it to AbstractCalcIO and then assign it to cio object
                Object obj = c.newInstance();

                cio = (AbstractCalcIO)obj;
```

And the properties file is :-

```
datafile=E:\\java\\calcproject\\cdata.txt
opmode=io.CalcIOSingle
calcmode=sc
```

So, finally i'm getting this notification :-

```
E:\java\calcproject>javac Main.java
Note: Main.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

**The solution will be for this problem:-**
For java version 10.0.2, default constructor will be used.

```
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(opm);
          //here need to use default constructor
        Constructor<?> cons = c.getDeclaredConstructor();
        Object obj = cons.newInstance();
        cio = (AbstractCalcIO)obj;
```

Comment: Insufficient information given to answer the question. Please include your build.gradle or pom.xml and somecontext for the project. (Also, I recommend upgrading to openjdk 11 as it is an LTS version)

Comment: This tells you why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393863/what-to-use-instead-of-class-newinstance

Comment: Just read it. It says: **Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.**. So, do that, and read the detailed message that you'll get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Class.newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) method bypasses the call to a default constructor, and hence possible thrown exceptions *(bad practice)*. This already longer was warned against.
Read the javadoc.

So use the default (parameterless) constructor:

```
Object obj = c.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Comment: I try it now that you commented. but sir it's still not working... My changed code section is :-
   Class c = Class.forName(opm);
   Object obj = c.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();

Comment: And `getConstructor()`? I hope there is a (default) constructor without parameters.

Comment: By the way with interfaces and [**java SPI**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html) one could do similar things faster, as reflection is costly, slow.

Comment: Sorry, getConstructor is for a public constructor, the best way, as invoking a private or protected constructor is dangerous. getDeclaredConstructor would need `setAccessible(true)`.